# When updating Cell in Excel using Fillo , getiing error as "NullPointerException"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am using below code,i have checked pathname and sheet name is all fine.
I am using fillo version fillo-1.15.

```
public class T_Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        try {
            com.codoid.products.fillo.Fillo fil_res = new com.codoid.products.fillo.Fillo();
            com.codoid.products.fillo.Connection con_res = fil_res
                    .getConnection("C:\\Users\\admin\\workspace\\Good Connect\\Test_Data/Result\\LifePlanner_Result.xlsx");
            String sql_res = "update Result_Data SET Product_ID = 'Sampoorna Raksha' Where TestCase_ID = 'TC1_SIS' ";
            System.out.println(sql_res);
            com.codoid.products.fillo.Recordset recordset_rec = con_res.executeQuery(sql_res);
            con_res.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception result set:" + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Error is below:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   Exception result set:java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.codoid.products.parser.SelectQueryParser.isWherePresent(SelectQueryParser.java:66)
>       at com.codoid.products.fillo.Select.getRecordset(Select.java:47)
>       at com.codoid.products.fillo.Connection.executeQuery(Connection.java:56)
>       at GoodSolutionAgence.T_Test.main(T_Test.java:89)

Comment: The exception is occurring in code that you haven't shown us.  So we can't help you.  But that's OK because the linked Q&A has **comprehensive** help on how to diagnose and fix NPEs for yourself.

Comment: @StephenC: Sorry, but the exception is occurring in a third-party library for which I don't believe the source code is unavailable.  Closing this question as a dupe of the canonical NPE question is therefore unhelpful as the asker is unable to debug this library.  As far as I can see, the problem regards deficient error handling in this library and I have an answer for it, therefore I have reopened this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error is here:

```
       com.codoid.products.fillo.Recordset recordset_rec = con_res.executeQuery(sql_res);
```

You are executing an `UPDATE` *statement*, not a `SELECT` *query*.  An `UPDATE` statement won't return a record set, just the number of rows it updated.  You therefore want to use `executeUpdate` in place of `executeQuery`:

```
       int numberOfRowsUpdated = con_res.executeUpdate(sql_res);
```

However, the Fillo library could at least have warned you that you were using the wrong method.  The fact that it threw a NullPointerException is in my opinion a bug in this library: it should handle this error condition better.

Answer (score -1):

Null Pointer Exception occurs when you try to reference a variable that has not been initialized

```
 com.codoid.products.fillo.Connection con_res = fil_res
                    .getConnection("C:\\Users\\admin\\workspace\\Good Connect\\Test_Data/Result\\LifePlanner_Result.xlsx");
```

In this case  the con_res might be null since  getConnection method is not functioning properly.

Now when  you try to execute

```
con_res.executeQuery(sql_res);
```

It results in Null Pointer Exception.

Check whether con_res gets initialized properly and check the path specified in getConnection method